# There is an error in XML document (0, 0)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've checked the three hits on SO that the error message's given me. None of them seemed to be relevant ([reader on element created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405832/issue-de-serializing-xml-to-object-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0), [document isn't empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405832/issue-de-serializing-xml-to-object-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0), [wrong library used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736815/purchase-orders-error-there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0)).

My class for *Mapping* looks like so.

```
[Serializable]
public class Mapping
{
  [XmlElement] public String Key { get; set; }
  [XmlElement] public String Field { get; set; }
  [XmlElement] public String Value { get; set; }
  [XmlElement] public bool Enable { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to assign manually using the code below, I get it to run as supposed to.

```
return characteristics.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Element("Name").Value,
  element => element.Descendants("DataMapping")
    .Select(felement => new Mapping
    {
      Key = felement.Element("Key").Value
    }));
```

However, when I try to impose deserialization on the very same data set being read, I get the error in subject.

```
return characteristics.ToDictionary(
  element => element.Element("Name").Value,
  element => element.Descendants("DataMapping")
    .Select(felement 
      => serializer.Deserialize(felement.CreateReader()) as Mapping));
```

I know (almost) for sure that I did something stupid and forgot something but I just can't see what... And I'm out of ideas to think of more things to try.

Comment: Is there an inner exception which might tell you whats wrong?

Comment: For XmlSerialization an empty Constructor is needed.

Comment: @derape There's no exception thrown at all. Not as far I can see. I'm not catching anything, at least.

Comment: @wonko79 Isn't an empty constructor available by default unless there's an explicit (and non-empty) one provided? As it is in my case? Or are you saying that we need to have a default constructor **explicitly** declared? I've tried *public Mapping() { }* but got the same misbehavior...

Comment: @KonradViltersten No constructor means you have a default empty constructor, so that isn't the problem.  What if you add a `[XmlRoot("DataMapping")]` to your `Mapping` class?  Or just rename it to `DataMapping`.

Comment: @juharr Bingo! Post it as a reply so I can accept it as an answer. Good call!

Comment: @KonradViltersten: XmlSerializer requires an explictely implemented empty constructor to work.

Comment: @wonko79 I tested adding it and it resulted in no difference. Also, I don't think the computer can distinguish between implicit and explicit empty constructor. At any rate, thanks for trying. See the accepted answer for details.   :)

Comment: @wonko79 No it doesn't.  The default empty constructor will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your element is named *DataMapping* and your class is named *Mapping*.  You can either rename the class to *DataMapping* or add the *XmlRoot* attribute to the class

```
[Serializable]
public class DataMapping
{
  ...
}
```

or...

```
[XmlRoot("DataMapping")]
public class Mapping
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Clatrity: +1. I took the liberty to edit it a bit. Hope it's OK.